# what does accessing zero element in R do?

Tags: r

if I have a vector `a<-c(3, 5, 7, 8)`

and run `a[1]`, not surprisingly I will get 3
but if I will run `a[0]` I basically get `numeric(0)`

What does this mean?
And what does this do?
How can I use it for normal reasons?

Comment: R has 1-based indexing unlike C. numeric(0) implies empty vector. You can try numeric(1), numeric(2) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors

As you can see it says: A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

Answer (score 8):

Others have answered what `x[0]` does, so I thought I'd expand on why it's useful: generating test cases.  It's great for making sure that your functions work with unusual data structure variants that users sometimes produce accidentally.

For example, it makes it easy to generate 0 row and 0 column data frames:

```
mtcars[0, ]
mtcars[, 0]
```

These can arise when subsetting goes wrong:

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl > 10, ]
```

But in your testing code it's useful to flag that you're doing it deliberately.

Comment: minor note - you'll need to use smth like `identical(mtcars[mtcars$cyl > 10,], mtcars[0,])` to do that test